# Access Query or Button to Fill Data from one to query to another without a Primary Key

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database with two tables in it, one is called Interviews and the other is called Giftcards.

The Interview table is a list of interviews conducted with a lot of variables on it including:
ClientID, InterviewType, ConductedInterview, StatusID, and InterviewDate.

The Giftcard table is a inventory table for gift cards including:
GiftcardNumber, CardType, Assigned, DateAdded, and ClientID.

I'm trying to design a form (? maybe button) that can batch assign an available gift card to a completed interview.

Basically for every interview on the table that meets the criteria (InterviewType=1 AND ConductedInterview=1 AND StatusID=2 OR 4) I need to assign an available card number (determined by CardType=1 AND Assigned=0) to that interview. The ClientID for the interview then needs to be copied to the ClientID field on the Giftcard table.

I cannot figure this out. The ClientID on the interview is filled out as part of the interview itself. But the ClientID field on the Giftcard table is blank until that particular card is assigned to that ClientID. Further complicating the issue, I need to always assign the oldest gift cards first. This is determined by the DateAdded field and then sorted within each date by the GiftcardNumber field in ascending order.

I need to be able to batch assign cards all with, ideally, one push of a button. We are assigning hundreds of gift cards at a time.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why did you tag MySql?

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this would be to use two recordsets.

The first would be based on the `Interviews` table, selecting those records that meet the criteria specified. The second would be based on the `Giftcards` table, again selecting the records that meet the requirements, sorting on two fields. You would then loop through these two recordsets until all those in the first recordset have been dealt with.

Perhaps something like this (Not fully tested as I haven't populated a full data set):

```
Sub sAssignGiftCards()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsInterview As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsGiftcard As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT ClientID FROM Interviews " _
        & " WHERE InterviewType=1 " _
        & " AND ConductedInterview=1 " _
        & " AND StatusID IN(2,4);"
    Set rsInterview = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsInterview.BOF And rsInterview.EOF) Then
        strSQL = "SELECT ClientID FROM Giftcards " _
            & " WHERE CardType=1 " _
            & " AND Assigned=0 " _
            & " ORDER BY DateAdded ASC, GiftcardNumber ASC;"
        Set rsGiftcard = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        If Not (rsGiftcard.BOF And rsGiftcard.EOF) Then
            Do
                rsGiftcard.Edit
                rsGiftcard!ClientID = rsInterview!ClientID
                rsGiftcard.Update
                rsGiftcard.MoveNext
                rsInterview.MoveNext
            Loop Until rsInterview.EOF
        End If
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsInterview.Close
    rsGiftcard.Close
    Set rsInterview = Nothing
    Set rsGiftcard = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sAssignGiftCards", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

You may wish to add extra fields to `rsInterview` so that you can update the allocation of a giftcard, and you may also want to add a sort order to this recordset so that there is an order of allocation here as well. Also, the `Assigned` field in `rsGiftcard` probably needs to be updated as well.

Regards,

Comment: Ok, so your code worked well and I really appreciate. I did make a few modifications to adjust for language. But it works great. I thought about your comment regarding the allocation of the gift card. What I really want to do is add a new record everytime a card is assigned  to a Receipts table with information from both the interview table and giftcard table. But I cant figure it out. Any Ideas? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please ask a new question, showing what you have done, and exactly what you want to do.